# Receiving warning: "cast_to_incompatible_type" and "cert_exp39_c_violation" in inherited class when scan coverity with SEI CERT rule

Tags: c++, coverity

I have a base class and a derived class implemented as bellow:

**BaseClass.h**

```
class BaseClass 
{
public:
    BaseClass() {}
    virtual ~BaseClass() = default;
};
```

**DerivedClass.h**

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    DerivedClass() : BaseClass() {}
    ~DerivedClass() {}
};
```

When I run scan coverity with SEI CERT Secure rule, I received warning "cast_to_incompatible_type" and "cert_exp39_c_violation" like below in the constructor, destructor of DerivedClass.

"1. cast_to_incompatible_type: Casting this of type DerivedClass * to incompatible type BaseClass *."

"2. cert_exp39_c_violation(CERT EXP39-C): Calling function BaseClass::~BaseClass() /*explicit =default*/ which accesses an object through a pointer this whose type BaseClass * is incompatible with the type of the object."

The problem I am facing is, I don't really know is this a bug in the CERT rule? And how to solve them ?

I hope I made my self clear and I apologize for such stretched out question.
Thanks in advance.

**[UPDATED]**

Regarding the problem of constructor, I tried to fix by not calling directly constructor of BaseClass like below, but still the problem is not solved.

**BaseClass.h**

```
class BaseClass 
{
public:
    BaseClass() {}  // empty constructor
    virtual ~BaseClass() = default;
};
```

**DerivedClass.h**

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    DerivedClass() {} // empty constructor
    ~DerivedClass() {}
};
```

Comment: Are you getting those error in these empty constructors ? If so, dump coverity and get better tools. If you are getting those errors in different code, please provide it, as we cannot guess :-)

Comment: @Jeffrey: Thank you for your comments. Yes, they are empty constructors. And I also tried solving the problem like [UPDATED], but still the problem is not solved. So I also think the my configs of the coverity tool is having problems. If there is any suggestion, please just help me.

Comment: `Casting this of type DerivedClass * to incompatible type BaseClass *` is total nonsense. You should ignore/disable this message it and file a bug to makers of Coverity.

Comment: If you have more than one class named `BaseClass` (which is illegal), it may throw Coverity off its tracks. Check that you don't have any such duplication.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: Thanks for your comments. I checked and don't have any such duplication, may be problem of Coverity tool, so I will create a bug file to makers of Coverity. One more time, thank you and Jeffrey so much.